# Connection between microservice(with Websocket ) and websocket client browser app through an API Gateway

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket, microservices, api-gateway

I have a websocket client and a Websocket Microservice and all the requests from the client goes through the API gateway.

***My Question:***

Will the **continuous connection** between the **websocket client** and a **Websocket Microservice** be established if the request from websocket client browser to Websocket Microservice goes through the API Gateway (after various steps like authentication) ?

***If not:***

then should I make the direct connection between them without the Gateway ? 
or there is some other workaround ?

Please help
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I made the direct connection between them without the Gateway. But is it possible to make connection through the  the API Gateway ( I want this because I wont have to do authentication for that  Websocket Microservice  separately) ?.

Comment: It depends on how you are doing your authentication? Is it cookie-based? Are you passing special headers back and forth? Websockets are just a layer on top of http and so any websocket request goes through the same logic (more or less) that a regular http request goes through.

Comment: BUT there is an API Gateway in the middle. User will request to Gateway then Gateway will request to websocket Microservice (  User => Gateway => Microservice ). Will there be a 2 way connection between user and websocket Microservice in this case ?

Comment: Most likely, though it depends on how you have it implemented. If you are using something like nginx to proxy requests to your backend, then nginx would handle all of this correctly.